# mysql select different record if value is not null

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select a record from a table, based on one column, but if that record contains an mapping id for another record, it should rather select the mapped record. e.g. in the following table:

```
id  name  mapping  
1   neil  2
2   Neil  NULL
3   bob   NULL
4   Bob   NULL
```

if I search for "neil" I want to return record 2 because it has a mapped record; but if I search for "bob" I should return record 3 because it is not mapped.

Something like this command (but it returns errors):

```
SELECT IF (
SELECT mapping FROM tbl_names WHERE name LIKE "neil" is null,
SELECT id, name FROM tbl_names WHERE name LIKE "neil",
SELECT id, name FROM tbl_names WHERE id = (SELECT mapping FROM tbl_names WHERE name LIKE "neil"
)
```

Comment: what if record 2 also has a mapped id like 4 then which record will be returned 2 or 4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    (
    CASE 
        WHEN mapping IS NOT NULL THEN mapping 
        ELSE id
    END) AS your_value
 from TABLE;
```